# Cant get value of ion-datetime using form group

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am using `Ionic 4.0.1` and `angular 7`. I am trying to use `ion-datetime` in a form group but I can't seem to retrieve the value. `Trip` is a component which I am using as a modal. What am I doing wrong?

home component

```
async onAddTrip(year: number) {
   const modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
     component: TripComponent,
     componentProps: {year: year},
   });
   return await modal.present();
}
```

home module

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: HomePage
      }
    ]),
    TripModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
      HomePage
  ],
  schemas: [
    CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
  ],
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

TripModule

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    TripComponent,
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    TripComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
  exports: [
  ],
  schemas: [
    CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
  ],

})

export class TripModule { }
```

trip.html

```
<form [formGroup]="form">  
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label position="stacked" color="primary">Start Date</ion-label>
    <ion-datetime
            name="start_date"
            display-format="MMM DD, YYYY"
            [min]="year"
            [max]="year"
            formControlName="start_date"
            ngDefaultControl
    >

    </ion-datetime>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-button fill="outline" color="primary" expand="block" (click)="onSave(form.value)">Save</ion-button>

</form>
```

trip component

```
form: FormGroup;
year = "2019";

constructor(private builder: FormBuilder) {
this.form = builder.group({
  'start_date': [],
});

onSave(data: TripInterface) {
    console.log(data);  // every other form field shows a value except start_date
    console.log(this.form.value); // again every other form field shows a value except start_date
    console.log(this.start_date); // no value
}
```

Comment: I tried your code with angular 7 and ionic 4, worked just fine for me. If you can, please create a stackblitz.

Comment: @AJT_82 I have updated my post with more information. `trip` is a component being used as a modal

Comment: That should make no difference, please create a demo showcasing this issue...

Comment: 1) Add this to bottom of trip.html and see if it sheds some light. `{{JSON.stringify(form.value)}}` 2) Have a look at this thread. https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/15408  3) You may find this useful too.